# Übersetzung von "something for you to amuse yourself with"

Tags: translation, english-to-german, infinitive, reflexive

> Here is something for you to amuse yourself with while waiting.

Wie kann man das ins Deutsche übersetzen?

> (a) Hier ist etwas, mit wem du dich während der Wartezeit amüsieren kannst.

Funktioniert die folgende direktere Übersetzung mit einer "zu"-Konstruktion?

> (b) Hier ist etwas für dich zum Amüsieren während der Wartezeit.

Ich bin mir besonders nicht sicher, weil "amüsieren" hier reflexiv sein sollte. Aber das Folgende klingt auch komisch.

> (c) Hier ist etwas für dich zum **sich** Amüsieren während der Wartezeit.

Comment: Eine idiomatische Variante wird auf das "amüsieren" überhaupt verzichten. Mögliche Sätze wären "Hiermit kannst du dir die Wartezeit vertreiben" o. ä.

Comment: Als Kommentar weil es keine Übersetzung ist: `Wartezeiten` werden im Deutschen sprichwörtlich `versüßt` http://www.linguee.de/deutsch-englisch/uebersetzung/wartezeit+versüßen.html

Comment: Meines Erachtens bekommt "sich amüsieren" schnell eine sexuelle Note. Kommt natürlich auf den Kontext an, aber wenn mir jemand etwas in die Hand drückt und mir sagt, dass ich mich damit amüsieren soll, dann klingt das für mich nach Sexspielzeug.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Zu den Vorschlägen:

> (a) Hier ist etwas, mit **d**em du dich während der Wartezeit amüsieren kannst.

Typo oder Absicht? "etwas" muss mit "dem", nicht "wem" kombiniert werden, sonst ok.

> (b) Hier ist etwas für dich zum Amüsieren während der Wartezeit.

Funktioniert auch.

Auch wenn "sich amüsieren" relexiv ist, brauchst Du das "sich" nicht, das "dich" übernimmt hier die Rolle des Refelexivpronomens.

Aber zur Wortwahl:
Auch wenn *to amuse oneself* / *sich amüsieren* wörtliche Übersetzungen sind und sicher nicht falsch, neigen Deutsche dazu, den Begriff etwas zurückhaltender einzusetzen, als z.B. US-Amerikaner (so meine Beobachtung). Wenn also das "etwas" aus dem Beispiel eine Zeitschrift ist, die der Friseur dem Kunden in die Hand drückt, würde man eher von "sich beschäftigen" oder "die Zeit überbrücken" sprechen.

Comment: "mit dem" ist schon arg umgangssprachlich, oder? Bei Übersetzungen würde ich "womit" nehmen.

Comment: Bei dem Beispiel gehe ich a) von gesprochener Sprache im informellen Umfeld aus und habe b) mich direkt an OP angelehnt. Und: Hier im SW würde kaum einer "womit" sagen....

Comment: Ich würde "womit" sagen, wenn nicht nicht eine Konstruktion mit "zum/zur" nehmen würde. Was ist denn SW?

Comment: SW: Südwesten von Deutschland, in meinem Fall, schwäbisch-badisches "Grenzgebiet".

Answer (score 1):

Mein erster Gedanke wäre gewesen:

> Hier ist etwas, womit du dich beschäftigen kannst. 
>   Hier, damit kannst du dich beschäftigen. 
>   Hier hast du was zum Zeitvertreib. (etwas umgangssprachlich)

So wie @Stephie gesagt hat, wird *(sich) amüsieren* im Deutschen nicht so häufig verwendet, und wenn, dann mMn auch mehr mit richtigen "high spirits" in Verbindung gebracht. (In meinem Heimatdialekt gibt es z.B. den leicht veralteten Ausdruck *Amüsemang*, phonetisch vom Französischen übernommen, was z.B. große Feste, Attraktionen und leichte Unterhaltung bezeichnet.)

Als stilistische Anmerkung fiele mir noch etwas ein ... die Formulierung "Hier ist (etwas, womit ...)" ist zwar verständlich, aber auch etwas unbequem, denn im Gegensatz zum Englischen bezieht sich *sein* wirklich nur auf die Existenz von etwas. (Bsp. *there is* - *es gibt*) Aus der reinen Wortwahl geht also nicht hervor, ob das *amusing something* nun dem Angesprochenen gereicht wird (was im Originalsatz durchaus so zu erkennen ist) oder ob es vielleicht vor ihm auf dem Boden liegt, oder ob er gar selbst darauf kommen soll, wo genau in seinem Umfeld es jetzt *ist*. Das *hier* in der Formulierung

> Hier, damit kannst du dich beschäftigen

entspricht meiner bescheidenen Meinung nach am meisten dem ursprünglichen "here is something (for you ...)".